# Microsoft Teams connector for Azure DevOps is not avaiable

Tags: azure-devops, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to connect my **Azure DevOps** to our newly created **Microsoft Teams** account. I'm using this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/services/teams?view=vsts) of Microsoft Docs. Unfortunately, I can not find `Azure DevOps` connector on Microsoft Teams connector list. I have the latest free version of Teams.

Is it removed from Microsoft Teams!? Where should I find it?

Comment: I just used the official document and I found Azure DevOps exactly where the document says I will.

Comment: @jac Are you using the free version of it?

Comment: @mehrandvd- Could you please ask your tenant admin to check if [external apps are enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/MicrosoftTeams/enable-features-office-365?redirectSourcePath=%252farticle%252fAdministrator-settings-for-Microsoft-Teams-3966a3f5-7e0f-4ea9-a402-41888f455ba2#apps)?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT I see other applications and can add them. I think Azure DevOps integration is not available in the free version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this integration to work, there are two prerequisites:

> 1. You should have Office365 account in order to integrate Visual Studio Team Services with Microsoft Teams.
> 2. Only VSTS accounts in the same organization (AAD tenant) can be used to integrate with your Microsoft Teams account.

Source: [Microsoft Teams Integration (Collaborate, Communicate and Celebrate)](https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vsts/teams/)

My guess is either of these prerequisites is not met.